# Select in ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have following code in my Handlebars template.

```
{{#each vouchers in content.vouchers}}                
    {{view Ember.Select viewName="hoa[]"
        prompt = "Select Account"
        contentBinding = "content.chartOfAccounts"
        optionLabelPath = "content.ca_name"
        optionValuePath = "content.id"
        selectionBinding = vouchers.ca_id
    }}
{{/each}}
```

The select is populating correctly, But it seems my selectionBinding is not working.
In vouchers.ca_id I have the id for current selected option. But it,s not working.

Another thing is I cannot set name for the created dropdown.

Comment: maybe it's just that you haven't put `vouchers.ca_id` into quotes. if not, some additional pieces of code (e.g. the corresponding model and controller) would make finding the problem easier.

Comment: Vouchers.ca_id is from the each loop, so it should be unquoted. Though i have tried that.

Answer (score 3):

`selectionBinding` will bind the entire selected model.  If you just want to pass the value, you should use `valueBinding` instead of `selectionBinding`.

As for the Select name, just use name="" instead of `viewName`:

```
{{view Ember.Select name="name_of_select"}}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i mean.

Comment: I was using ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js. I just updated to rc2 now it works.